# How do I increase or decrease a field price in SQL?

Tags: sql, select

Table example:

DVD = tablename

Fields:

Price
DVDName

For increasing price by lets say 5% my code is :

```
update DVD 
set Price = price * 1.05
```

For decreasing:

```
update DVD
set Price = price * 0.95
```

Now I am not sure if they are missing any action queries or anything. Would you say they are correct?

Thanks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may the right place for this question.

Comment: Looks just fine. Did you try them? What happened?

Comment: The only word of caution I would have would be with rounding. I would be asking myself how critical these prices are, what the data type is, whether to round to 2 decimal places or to maintain the precision if you need it for further calculations.

Answer (score 0):

For Increasing 5%

```
Update DVD
SET Price = Price + ((Price * 5) / 100)
```

For Decreasing 5%

```
Update DVD
SET Price = Price - ((Price * 5) / 100)
```

Comment: @Praveen 5% should be based on price not fixed right

Comment: What's'a difference? 5% is 5% independently of how you calculate it. Real problem may be rounding, but we don't know original price field type.

Answer (score 0):

```
update DVD Set Price = Price * 1.05 Where DVDName='SomeName'
```